# Outlook 2016 for Mac, addFileAttachmentAsync not working for inline pictures

Tags: javascript, office-js, outlook-web-addins

Trying the following sample (as mentioned here https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Office.context.mailbox.item?product=outlook&version=v1.5 )

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync
(
  "http://i.imgur.com/WJXklif.png",
  "cute_bird.png",
  {
    isInline: true
  },
  function (asyncResult) {
    Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync(
      "<p>Here's a cute bird!</p><img src='cid:cute_bird.png'>",
      {
        "coercionType": "html"
      },
      function (asyncResult) {

      }
    );
  }
);
```

This works perfectly fine on Outlook for Windows. But it doesn't for Mac. The attachment does get included in the mail. However the picture will not be displayed.

I've tried the same with different image formats and setting the isInline option to false.

Is there any way to make this feature work for Mac?